# Async update in mongodb with C# - having trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have the following:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ViewAll(Patient p)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
        string db_name = "test" + userId;
        var database = client.GetDatabase(db_name);
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("patients");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name", p.Name.ToString());


        NewPatient np = new NewPatient();
        np.Age = 100;
        np.Name = p.Name;

        np.Encounters.Add(new Encounter(p.Date, p.History_Illness, p.Past_History, p.Physical_Exam, 
            p.Tests, p.Diagnosis, p.Treatment, p.Prescriptions, p.Referrals));

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(np);


        MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument document2
            = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(json);

      collection.InsertOne(document2);
        var h = Mongo(p, filter, document2);

        return Content(json);       

    }


    private async Task Mongo(Patient p, FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> f, BsonDocument document)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
        string db_name = "test" + userId;
        var database = client.GetDatabase(db_name);

        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("patients");
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name", p.Name.ToString());

        var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(f, document);

    }
```

I want to Update, but I cannot Update.  However, I did successfully Insert.  However, the Insert was only there to debug, I really just want to Update.  In the mean time, I suppose deleting a record and inserting a record is essentially equivalent to one update, so I guess my quick fix for now is to just copy and delete.
But would really love to hear about if it's possible to make this Update function work.

Comment: You guess wrong. Perhaps a tour of [MongoDB CRUD Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/) would give you a better understanding and a basic for looking for the correct methods and operators. Updates really should not "replace" as a matter of general best practice, unless you know you explicitly mean that. And only then once you understand the CRUD operations concepts.

Comment: I am using C#, and only async methods are available:  https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update/

Comment: By reading your question, I think you need to understand the basic CRUD concepts first as you clearly don't understand the different operations and modifiers. Reading the section I gave you, should give you enough understanding to know which "driver methods" to apply. The basics are fairly language agnostic, and you generally should learn them. That's the advice, which I suggest you take.